# How to automate a splitButton using Rautomation ( adapter msuia)

Tags: rautomation

I am trying to automate IE11 notification bar ( while downloading file) using Rautomation. Using MSUIA adapter I am able to catch the the save button. But I want to use Save As to supply the file location and name. But I cannot do that.

When seeing with UIspy I see that there is a splitbutton with name "Save". This splitbutton has another child splitbutton with name "" ( which is basically the down arrow) - I am not able to get to this control.

```
iemainwindow_local = RAutomation::Window.new(:class=>"IEFrame" , :adapter => :ms_uia )
ienotificationbar_frame = iemainwindow_local.child(:class=>"Frame Notification Bar")
ienotificationbar = ienotificationbar_frame.child(:class=>"DirectUIHWND")
if ienotificationbar.exists?
  ienotificationbar.activate
  sleep 1
  mycontrol = ienotificationbar.control(:value =>"Save")
  mycontrol2= mycontrol.control(:children_only => true) 
  mycontrol2.exist?
  mycontrol.click
end
```

Getting error at this line mycontrol2= mycontrol.control(:children_only => true)

```
undefined method `control' for #<RAutomation::Adapter::MsUia::Control:0x4108e60>
```

Any idea how to get over this block?

I understand that there should be a menu and menuitems associated with the splitButton and when I click on down arrow besides Save, at UISpy I see that menu/ menu item is getting created directly under Desktop window ( though the processID is same ) - how to catch the menuitem Save as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

Unfortunately, the `:ms_uia` adapter for `RAutomation` is not able to do this in its current form. I know this because I have written a lot of the UIA adapter for it :) The problem is that the current API doesn't allow you to really walk the tree like that (as you found out) because the `Control` class doesn't have a `#control` method. If the "Save" button had a native window handle, you'd be able to do this:

```rb
ieframe = RAutomation::Window.new(class: 'IEFrame')
save = RAutomation::Window.new(hwnd: ieframe.control(value: 'Save').hwnd)
save.control(index: 0)
```

Since it does not, unfortunately there isn't a reliable way to get down to it that I am aware of since it doesn't have any identifying properties about it (other than being a child of the "Save" button).

### Alternative

I've [written another gem](https://github.com/northwoodspd/uia) called `uia`, which acts as a low-level wrapper around UI Automation and allows you to work more closely with UI Automation and interact with it how you see it within tools like UI Spy. Eventually, I will use this gem in `RAutomation` but have not had the time yet. To get down to the "Save As..." split button control in your circumstance, you can do this:

```rb
ieframe = UIA.find_element(title: /Thanks for downloading/)
save_as = ieframe.find(name: 'Save').find(control_type: :split_button)
save_as.as(:invoke).invoke
```

The `save_as.as(:invoke)` will treat the found "Save As" `Element` as something that implements the `Invoke` pattern, and then you can call the `#invoke` method to get the menu to pop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Levi for your response. In my present solution I bypassed this by calculating the position of the down arrow and mouse_clicking on that. But the solution is not elegant and I do not like that. I shall try your gem now.